# Why would you need to use the DispId annotation in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com

for example

```
public interface IWMPSettings

        [DispId(101)]
        bool autoStart { get; set; }
        [DispId(102)]
        int balance { get; set; }
```

is it useful or is it just auto-generated for compiler? What are COM dispatch identifiers for and when would they be needed in a .NET context?

Comment: Fair enough, but perhaps more pertinent then would be to ask what COM dispatch identifiers are, since MSDN tells you this is what `DispId` is for!

Comment: It means you are doing it wrong.  Project + Add Reference, Browse tab, select c:\windows\system32\wmp.dll.  You now have the WMPLib.IWMPSettings type defined.

Comment: @WillVousden Ironically enough, this page is #1 on the search results.

Comment: @lorddev That tickles me!

Comment: Example of where a DispID is useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796838/3195477

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In short, yes it is useful, but only for COM dispatch:

[The DispIdAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute.aspx) (from MSDN):

> Specifies the COM dispatch identifier (DISPID) of a method, field, or property.
>
> This attribute contains the DISPID for the method, field, or property it describes. Unique DISPIDs are typically assigned by the common language runtime, but you can use this attribute to assign a specific DISPID to a method. When importing a type library, this attribute is applied to all methods with assigned DISPIDs. This ensures that any managed implementation of the same method retains the same DISPID if exposed to COM.

Comment: I don't understand. I'm not c# programmer. What that means for a me as developer?

Comment: @IAdapter If your types are COM visible and you expect them to be invoked via COM code (not .Net) then you *may* need to use this attribute. It will not affect any code that calls these methods from .Net however, so if your code is all .Net, the attribute is redundant.

Comment: Is this the right way to follow some of the above: Basically if you are going to take each of your methods, properties, and fields and implement it only one time, in the same assembly, in the same class, etc., this is unnecessary, *even* when using COM in VB6 or whatever else to access it.  However if you were to take a method, field, or property and implement it in different dlls or do something else like that (maybe supporting different platforms manually, maybe porting old code to a newer language, etc.), *then* that is when this comes in really handy, as it will maintain the same identity.

Comment: Is that the correct context and everything of the quote above?

Comment: @Panzercrisis I agree with your comments, I don't think this really answers the intent of the question either (thought it does so in a strict sense... it doesn't convey when these DispIDs are useful)