# Does .NET have predefined constant values for DispIds?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop

The [DispId attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dispidattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) can be passed certain values which confer specific meaning to anyone consuming your COM object.

e.g., [here is one example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4796838/3195477).

Typical advice seems to be to just hardcode whichever "magic number" suits your purpose. But since .NET included the `DispIdAttribute` **I was expecting a list of constants to go along with it - but haven't been able to find one. Does such a thing exist?**

For the record the DispId values I'm talking about are:

```
DISPID_COLLECT         -8    
DISPID_CONSTRUCTOR     -6    
DISPID_DESTRUCTOR      -7    
DISPID_EVALUATE        -5     
DISPID_NEWENUM         -4    
DISPID_PROPERTYPUT     -3    
DISPID_UNKNOWN         -1    
DISPID_VALUE            0
```

ref https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221242(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If I remember my old VB6 days, pretty sure those values were magic numbers in there too :/

Comment: I am almost certain there are none. Even the MSDN examples from your link just use plain integer literals

Comment: Only two of these are ever expected to be used by a client app.  DISPID_VALUE indicates the default property, in C# that is the indexer.  DISPID_NEWENUM indicates the iterator, in C# you automatically get it when you implement IEnumerator.  These assignments are automatic without having to use [DispId], thus no corresponding declarations are available in the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used .NET Reflector to search for "dispid" in all assemblies in the .NET framework. It would appear that there are no *public* consts or enums that expose these standard DISPIDs. There are a couple of internal classes -- `System.Dynamic.ComDispIds` and `System.Windows.Forms.NativeMethods+ActiveX` -- that expose these constants, but you cannot get at them without reflection.

Comment: Clever approach